# Is performance of DB slow in sql server 2005 express compared to sql server 2005 enterprise?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is performance of DB slow in sql server 2005 express compared to sql server 2005 enterprise ?

Comparison between sql-server 2005 and express 2005 is [**here**](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx)

Comparison between sql-server 2008 and express 2008 is [**here**](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx)

Comment: Further if i may add sql server 2008 express more better ?

Comment: ???? I don't understand what you're asking for? More of what? Better than what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Express editions are the full, regular SQL Server core code - so from that point, there's no performance difference.

Sure, the Enterprise edition has a few additional goodies, like indexed views and so forth, which might make things faster. But for the normal, average SQL query, there's no significant performance difference to be expected.

SQL Server Express editions also have some limitations, such as supporting only a single CPU (core), max. of 1 GB of RAM, max of 4 GB of database size.

But unless your query would exceed any of those limits, I don't see any reason why SQL Server Express would be any slower than SQL Server Enterprise edition.